# What kind of rifle used this shell case?

Tags: military, world-war-one, weapons

[image]

Please, anyone able to tell me what kind of shell is it and what mean this symbol  on the bottom ?  Is it from 1917?

Comment: Some idea of the scale would be very helpful. The easiest way to give that is to add another photograph, with a ruler alongside the casing.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for the rifle model or the bullet's manufacturer? Because the Symbol you've surrounded in Red almost certainly relates to the latter.

Answer (score 3):

> **What kind of rifle used this shell case?**

I'm no expert but from what I've read ...

The marking "6PR" suggests a 6-pounder, for example the [QF 6-pounder Hotchkiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QF_6-pounder_Hotchkiss)

[image]
<sup>Image is Public Domain - Crown copyright expired</sup>

The arrow mean accepted into service

"N" means Naval service

"IV" means a Mark 4 casing

"CF" means cordite filled

"1917" is the year of manufacture"

> **what mean this symbol on the bottom?**

As sempaiscuba commented: "The symbol is the original manufacturer of the shell case." Often initials were used but sometimes the "original contractor" used a trademark of some sort.

Here's an example from a different calibre:

[image: Cartridge base markings]

From "[Treatise on Ammunition, 10th Edition, War Office, 1915](https://bulletpicker.com/pdf/Treatise%20on%20Ammunition,%201915.pdf)"

Comment: RedGrittyB, thank you very much for the information!